# Deploying a next js or react app on aws Amplify without using console or cli

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, deployment, cloud, aws-amplify

I have a use case where I am automating some things and I want to deploy the next 13 app programmatically without using the console or the cli. Is there a way or some kind of API that AWS offers that we can use to deploy the app by hitting an endpoint or something? I have found this [resourse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/amplify/) that is providing methods like `createAppCommand` and `createDeploymentCommand` but some of the things are unclear to me like where I need to send the post request and what do I need to pass as the config in the `amplifyClient`. Take a look at this for example:

```
import { AmplifyClient, CreateAppCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-amplify"; // ES Modules import
// const { AmplifyClient, CreateAppCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-amplify"); // CommonJS import
const client = new AmplifyClient(config);
const input = { // CreateAppRequest
  name: "STRING_VALUE", // required
  description: "STRING_VALUE",
  repository: "STRING_VALUE",
  platform: "WEB" || "WEB_DYNAMIC" || "WEB_COMPUTE",
  iamServiceRoleArn: "STRING_VALUE",
  oauthToken: "STRING_VALUE",
  accessToken: "STRING_VALUE",
  environmentVariables: { // EnvironmentVariables
    "<keys>": "STRING_VALUE",
  },
  enableBranchAutoBuild: true || false,
  enableBranchAutoDeletion: true || false,
  enableBasicAuth: true || false,
  basicAuthCredentials: "STRING_VALUE",
  customRules: [ // CustomRules
    { // CustomRule
      source: "STRING_VALUE", // required
      target: "STRING_VALUE", // required
      status: "STRING_VALUE",
      condition: "STRING_VALUE",
    },
  ],
  tags: { // TagMap
    "<keys>": "STRING_VALUE",
  },
  buildSpec: "STRING_VALUE",
  customHeaders: "STRING_VALUE",
  enableAutoBranchCreation: true || false,
  autoBranchCreationPatterns: [ // AutoBranchCreationPatterns
    "STRING_VALUE",
  ],
  autoBranchCreationConfig: { // AutoBranchCreationConfig
    stage: "PRODUCTION" || "BETA" || "DEVELOPMENT" || "EXPERIMENTAL" || "PULL_REQUEST",
    framework: "STRING_VALUE",
    enableAutoBuild: true || false,
    environmentVariables: {
      "<keys>": "STRING_VALUE",
    },
    basicAuthCredentials: "STRING_VALUE",
    enableBasicAuth: true || false,
    enablePerformanceMode: true || false,
    buildSpec: "STRING_VALUE",
    enablePullRequestPreview: true || false,
    pullRequestEnvironmentName: "STRING_VALUE",
  },
};
const command = new CreateAppCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
// { // CreateAppResult
//   app: { // App
//     appId: "STRING_VALUE", // required
//     appArn: "STRING_VALUE", // required
//     name: "STRING_VALUE", // required
//     tags: { // TagMap
//       "<keys>": "STRING_VALUE",
//     },
//     description: "STRING_VALUE", // required
//     repository: "STRING_VALUE", // required
//     platform: "WEB" || "WEB_DYNAMIC" || "WEB_COMPUTE", // required
//     createTime: new Date("TIMESTAMP"), // required
//     updateTime: new Date("TIMESTAMP"), // required
//     iamServiceRoleArn: "STRING_VALUE",
//     environmentVariables: { // EnvironmentVariables // required
//       "<keys>": "STRING_VALUE",
//     },
//     defaultDomain: "STRING_VALUE", // required
//     enableBranchAutoBuild: true || false, // required
//     enableBranchAutoDeletion: true || false,
//     enableBasicAuth: true || false, // required
//     basicAuthCredentials: "STRING_VALUE",
//     customRules: [ // CustomRules
//       { // CustomRule
//         source: "STRING_VALUE", // required
//         target: "STRING_VALUE", // required
//         status: "STRING_VALUE",
//         condition: "STRING_VALUE",
//       },
//     ],
//     productionBranch: { // ProductionBranch
//       lastDeployTime: new Date("TIMESTAMP"),
//       status: "STRING_VALUE",
//       thumbnailUrl: "STRING_VALUE",
//       branchName: "STRING_VALUE",
//     },
//     buildSpec: "STRING_VALUE",
//     customHeaders: "STRING_VALUE",
//     enableAutoBranchCreation: true || false,
//     autoBranchCreationPatterns: [ // AutoBranchCreationPatterns
//       "STRING_VALUE",
//     ],
//     autoBranchCreationConfig: { // AutoBranchCreationConfig
//       stage: "PRODUCTION" || "BETA" || "DEVELOPMENT" || "EXPERIMENTAL" || "PULL_REQUEST",
//       framework: "STRING_VALUE",
//       enableAutoBuild: true || false,
//       environmentVariables: {
//         "<keys>": "STRING_VALUE",
//       },
//       basicAuthCredentials: "STRING_VALUE",
//       enableBasicAuth: true || false,
//       enablePerformanceMode: true || false,
//       buildSpec: "STRING_VALUE",
//       enablePullRequestPreview: true || false,
//       pullRequestEnvironmentName: "STRING_VALUE",
//     },
//     repositoryCloneMethod: "SSH" || "TOKEN" || "SIGV4",
//   },
// };
```